# SQL - Field has two values for a record, want to only show one of the values based on total within another field, then show totals for both values

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api

So I'm trying to create a top ten list, but some companies have 2 BUSTYPES associated with, I want the result to sum the values while only including the BUSTYPE associated with the larger value

Example Query

```
SELECT TOP 10 ID, COMPANY, BUSTYPE, sum(value) as VALUES
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID, COMPANY, BUSTYPE
ORDER BY VALUES desc
```

Relevant output table 1:

```
ID   COMPANY   BUSTYPE  VALUES
123  orange     Large    1820
```

Relevant output table 2:

```
ID   COMPANY   BUSTYPE  VALUES
123  orange     Small    294
```

IDEAL TABLE End Result (2114 = 1820 + 294) and the larger value is associated with the Large Bustype so it is shown

```
ID   COMPANY   BUSTYPE  VALUES
123  orange     Large    2114
```

Also attaching an image for further visualizations 
[image]

My end goal for this to create a table I can join with to default to the BUSTYPE in my main table, so I don't have to worry about a company having 2 BUSTYPE

or find a way to do this to my ENTIRE DATA SET!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ID, COMPANY,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN BUSTYPE END) as BUSTYPE, 
       SUM(value) as VALUES
FROM (SELECT T.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, COMPANY ORDER BY VALUE DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM TABLE T
     ) T
GROUP BY ID, COMPANY
ORDER BY VALUES desc;
```

You can also use `FIRST_VALUE()` so you don't need the conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ID, COMPANY, FIRST_BUSTYPE, 
       SUM(value) as VALUES
FROM (SELECT T.*,
             FIRST_VALUE(BUSTYPE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, COMPANY ORDER BY VALUE DESC) AS FIRST_BUSTYPE
      FROM TABLE T
     ) T
GROUP BY ID, COMPANY, FIRST_BUSTYPE
ORDER BY VALUES desc
```

Comment: Hi what does "seqnum" stand for, and let's say I have a table with more columns, would I just partition by those additional columns?

Comment: @JohnVuu . . . It is an incrementing value that is `1` for the rows that you want.  As for the `partition by` -- that should be whatever uniquely defines a row in the result set.  `id` is probably sufficient, but I put in the company as well to be safe.